# How to transfer files from MacBook Pro to laptop using WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, macbook, data-transfer

I have two laptops:

1. MacBook Pro
2. Dell XPS 15 L-501z

I want to know how can I transfer files via WiFi between them?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a Wi-Fi router or access point? If so, assign each of them an IP address, configure sharing on the Windows and Mac machines, and then connect using Finder from the Macs.

In OS X there's a specific option in `System Preferences` > `Sharing` for allowing Windows machines to connect. Enable the `File Sharing` option, click the `Options` button, and select `Share files and folders using SMB (Windows)`.

I'm not sure how reliable an ad-hoc wireless network will be, as I've never set one up between OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like an ad-hoc 'no configuration' solution try my open source project [cross copy](http://www.cross-copy.net):

1. Open http://www.cross-copy.net on both computers (on OSX you can also use the [command line client](https://github.com/rodja/cross-copy/blob/master/cmd-client/cross-copy)).
2. enter the same unique phrase on both websites
3. start uploading files --- they will instantly appear on the other side for downloading

Answer (score 0):

If the network is up then you can also use FTP or TFTP or SCP etc. to transfer files without needing to share anything.

The FTP method goes like this:

1. Install an FTP server on one of the nodes.
2. Run the FTP server on that node and it will bind to the IP address of that system.
3. Use an FTP client on the other node to connect to the server and start transferring files.

That's it... So simple and working with everything, even iPhone + Windows. There are lots of free FTP servers on the web just have a search and you'll see.